# Ng-if to not display adsense ads on angular localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the following to attempt to stop adsense ads from loading in angular"

```
<div class="" ng-if="window.location.host.indexOf('localhost') < 0">
ads here
</div>
```

The script logs okay in the console but doesn't work when live. Is this due to the difference between the time the check ran and the resolved host? Or should I be using something like:

```
<div class="" ng-if="$location.host().indexOf('localhost') < 0">
ads here
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you can define something like:

```
$scope.enableAds = $window.location.host.indexOf('localhost') < 0;
```

and in your HTML

```
<div class="" ng-if="enableAds">ads here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! No idea why I didn't do this is in the first place. I think it's because I like to avoid having too many scope variables and handle logic like that directly on the HTML elements. I would also be curious if there was away to handle in directly. :) Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. ng-if requires an expression.
 Based on AngularJS Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression
    Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of subtle bugs.